# PHP, RFI, and keeping things secure

Tags: php, security

I am working on a website which the good user inputs a website domain name, http://www.mysite.com.

But I have been reading about remote file inclusion (RFI), and it is pretty interesting. Simply by adding ?page=http://www.mysite.com/index.php? or something near that I get some type of error (500).
Other peoples sites using wordpress/ PHP if I do the same I also get an error.

I do not know if this means the script was run, but how can I keep my input clean? I already use REGEX, but I want the user to be able to input any website and process it accordingly. I certainly do not want significant security holes anywhere in my script.

Good night here in Boston on the East Coast [EST]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP 500 error you're seeing sounds like something that [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/), a module for Apache, is generating. mod_security scans all input against a set of security rules, one of which probably is checking for RFI. This is a first line of defense.

To protect against RFI, there's a few other things you can do. First, since PHP 5.2.0, there is an option called [allow_url_include](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include). When set to false, this will cause PHP to throw an error whenever a file is being included that is an URL. Most people will want to have this setting set to *false*.

Additionally, there's sanitizing your input. There's a variety of ways to do it, indeed like using regex, but you could also look at the [filter extension](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html). Just be sure to be strict enough, you wouldn't want to allow someone to sneak in a `../../` and having a peek a level or two higher in the file hierarchy.

The safest, but sometimes also a very impractical, way to security file access would be to use a whitelist of the exact files that would be allowed to be included.